# Accessing class functions

Tags: objective-c, class, function, uiview

I have created a UIView class. In this class it has touchesbegan and touches moved functions etc. When I create an instance of this class in my UIView controller they don't work.

Is it not possible for the instance to access these functions? I know the class works because if I drag a UIView onto the View Controller and assign it with the class I can drag it and resize it etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have created a UIView class. In this class it has touchesbegan and
>   touches moved functions etc. When I create an instance of this class
>   in my UIView controller they don't work.

Check the `userInteractionEnabled` property of the view. The default value for any UIView is YES, so your view should track touches, but you may have disabled the view in your storyboard or .xib file.

> Is it not possible for the instance to access these functions?

It's possible, and the entire touch handling mechanism relies on it. If your view is enabled, and it's not covered up by some other view, and there aren't any gesture recognizers that are stealing its touch events, it should be receiving touch messages.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure I have explained it right. I have a UIView class called resizeView in here there is a create view function. Then touchesBegan and touchesMoved function. In my UIView controller I import resizeView create and instance from the class but nothing happens when I touch the view.

Comment: @Mike Sounds like it might be helpful to post your code. Before you do that, though, put breakpoints in the methods in question so you can see if they're getting called at all. If not, then there's an issue with the view (as described above) or its position (or lack of) in the view hierarchy. You can call the `recursiveDescription` method in the debugger to get a good look at the view hierarchy.